# Exchange 2003 email bouncing from a public folder

Tags: email, exchange-2003, email-bounces

I am having a rather annoying problem within Exchange 2003. At the moment, mail comes in on mail1@mail.com which is picked up by a public folder which everybody has access to. This is auto forwarded (in delivery options) to mail2@mail.com. This works perfectly fine, however, somehow an email will additionally get sent to other email addresses, these are people that have left the organisation, and therefore have no user account, nor email addresses. The email then bounces back to mail1@mail.com- which is auto forwarded to mail2@mail.com.

This has become very annoying, and I cannot find where this is occuring in exchange. My last thought is that somebody has setup an outlook rule (client/server side) which auto forwards these emails to these non-existent users. If this is the case, is it possible to find out which user has done this?

Many thanks

Alistair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public folders can be "moderated" - it's a property that someone with the proper permissions can edit from within Outlook:  Property sheet of the folder in question -> Administration -> Moderated Folder button

[Tutorial here](http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Creating-Using-Moderated-Public-Folders-Exchange-Server.html).